# Is is possible to have transparent background image?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have transparent background image using CSS3?

```
background: url(../img/bg_paperlines.jpg) repeat-x;
```

Using `rgba(255,255,255,0.5)` will set transparent background on the DIV, but the image will hide that.

I know I can have transparent `<img>`, but that's not what I'm after.

And I have to make sure that the `text` within the DIV is not set to transaprent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a PNG with alpha transparency instead of jpg.

Comment: I know - I was just wondering if it was possible to set transparency using CSS3.

Comment: @Steven: I've never heard of any property that can do that. What you could do is put the background-image in a separate div and apply transparency to the div. You'll have to position it and lower the z-index, so it stays at the top and behind the actual content.

Comment: Yep - I probably have to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have transparency using

```
opacity: 0.5;
```

but that's it, if you want per-pixel opacity, you have to use a image format that supports it like PNG.